# Parent div to follow height of child - for child without float

Tags: css, height, parent-child

The only answer I can find to my problem is clear the float - but I have non. So hope you can help with another answer :-)

Here is my code, and I am trying to make the parent div of a button follow the expansion done by the padding.

```
<div class="button">
    <a href="#">add</a>
</div>
```

And css

```
.button {
    background-color: #ccc; }
.button a {
background-color: #96BD1E;
color: black;
font-size: large;
padding: 6px 12px;
width: 120px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-opera-border-radius: 5px;
-khtml-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
height: 59px;
margin: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 5px 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px 5px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px 5px;
    clear: both;
}
```

And here is an example of it to play with http://jsfiddle.net/zNLVZ/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your css to this:

```
.button {
background-color: #ccc; 
}
.button a {
display:inline-block;
background-color: #96BD1E;
color: black;
font-size: large;
padding: 6px 12px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-opera-border-radius: 5px;
-khtml-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
margin: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 5px 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px 5px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px 5px;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but didn't change anything

Comment: Oops yeah that's cause I missed out the major part of it the addition of display:inline-block; Try it again http://jsfiddle.net/zNLVZ/2/

Comment: Great thanks, that was the trick I was looking for. I better remember that one :-)